# Replacing multiple lines in a file

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I try to make, the line from the first array is read from a file and is replaced with a line from the second array, so some times with different lines. I made a script, but I do not understand why it does not work.

```
$OldStrings = @(
    "desktopwidth:i:1440",
    "desktopheight:i:900",
    "winposstr:s:0,1,140,60,1596,999"
)
$NewStrings = @(
    "desktopwidth:i:1734",
    "desktopheight:i:990",
    "winposstr:s:0,1,50,7,1800,1036"
)

$LinesArray = Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\My Copy\Default.rdp'
$LinesCount = $LinesArray.Count
for ($i=0; $i -lt $LinesCount; $i++) {
    foreach ($OldString in $OldStrings) {
        foreach ($NewString in $NewStrings) {
            if ($LinesArray[$i] -like $OldString) {
                $LinesArray[$i] = $LinesArray[$i] -replace $OldString, $NewString
                Write-Host "`nline" $i "takes on value:" $LinesArray[$i] "`n" -ForegroundColor Gray
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The file is probably why it is not read at all.

After executing the script, I see only

```
line 2 takes on value: desktopwidth:i:1734 

line 3 takes on value: desktopwidth:i:1734 

line 5 takes on value: desktopwidth:i:1734
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking through the string arrays twice. You want to do two loops, one for each line in the file AND another for each count in the lines you're replacing. I think this should work:

```
$OldStrings = @(
"desktopwidth:i:1440",
"desktopheight:i:900",
"winposstr:s:0,1,140,60,1596,999"
)
$NewStrings = @(
"desktopwidth:i:1734",
"desktopheight:i:990",
"winposstr:s:0,1,50,7,1800,1036"
)

$LinesArray = Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\My Copy\Default.rdp'

# loop through each line
for ($i=0; $i -lt $LinesArray.Count; $i++)
{
    for ($j=0;$j -lt $OldStrings.Count; $j++)
    {
        if ($LinesArray[$i] -match $OldStrings[$j])
        {
            $LinesArray[$i] = $LinesArray[$i] -replace $OldStrings[$j],$NewStrings[$j]
            Write-Host "`nline" $i "takes on value:" $LinesArray[$i] "`n" -ForegroundColor Gray
        }
    }
}

$LinesArray | Set-Content -Path 'C:\temp\My Copy\Default.rdp'
```

Comment: Those trailing backticks in the arrays are not required. ALso be careful that `-replace` is a regex operator

Comment: @Matt I don't know how those got there. I wouldn't have added them and they weren't in his original answer I copied from ha.

Comment: If you didn't want to use the regex operator, use `$LinesArray[$i] = $LinesArray[$i].Replace($OldStrings[$j],$NewStrings[$j])`

Comment: @ShawnEsterman messages in the console are displayed correctly, but nothing changes in the file

Comment: Your content is currently stored in a variable. I assumed you knew this. If you want to put the modified content back to the file, add this to the end of your script: `$LinesArray | Set-Content -Path 'C:\temp\My Copy\Default.rdp'`

Comment: @ShawnEsterman it works, thanks. Initially, my script took files through foreach, this one I did based on it https://pastebin.com/hrRhqRUB

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bother checking the lines to look for matches. Since you have the replacements ready just do the replacements outright anyway. Should be faster this way as well.

```
$stringReplacements = @{
    "desktopwidth:i:1440" = "desktopwidth:i:1734"
    "desktopheight:i:900" = "desktopheight:i:990"
    "winposstr:s:0,1,140,60,1596,999" = "winposstr:s:0,1,50,7,1800,1036"
}
$path = 'C:\temp\My Copy\Default.rdp'
# Read the file in as a single string.
$fileContent = Get-Content $path | Out-String
# Iterate over each key value pair
$stringReplacements.Keys | ForEach-Object{
    # Attempt the replacement for each key/pair search/replace pair
    $fileContent =$fileContent.Replace($_,$stringReplacements[$_])
}
# Write changes back to file.
# $fileContent | Set-Content $path
```

`$stringReplacements` is a key value hash of search and replace strings. I don't see you writing the changes back to file so I left a line on the end for you to uncomment.

You could add in checks to do the replacements still if you value the `write-host` lines but I figured that was for debugging and you already know how to do that.

Comment: thank you for the example, I have uncommented the last line, but for some reason the script does not write the changes back to the file

Comment: Ha. That was a rookie mistake for me. I forgot to write the changes back to the file contents.  It would have just written then to std output.

Comment: Should be fine now

Comment: thanks, it works, unfortunately I can not put an estimate yet